# Magento Add Extra field in Address form

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, template

I need to add some extra fields to the existing customer address form in magento. Please help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what these fields should do? Should they be stored with the customer, emailed to the admin, and what kind of fields should they be?
Also I'm guessing we're talking about the address book in the customer account section. Would this mean that these fields should also be available in the checkout?

Comment: I am talking about the billing address at the time of checkout. There are few fields for the customer billing address like Firstname, Lastname , address ect. But what if I need to add few more fields like village, street etc. I think now you are getting my point.

Comment: I suggest putting the extra info in your question to get more answers, make it more clear for people. :)

Comment: Yes, I am  talking about the address book in the customer account section.and I also want these fields should also be available in the checkout.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please checkout below link

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page

or

http://magentoabid.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-add-custom-field-in-one-page.html

it may help you